# VB.NET Assigning Control to Other Control

Tags: vb.net, forms, controls

i was just wondering about this

```
    Dim _Label As Label = Form1.Label1
    _Label.Text = "New Text" ' This work Form1.Label1.Text changed to  "New Text"
```

is this like ByRef is this pointer ,,, how this work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is a pointer.  In .NET, some types of variables always work like pointers while other types do not.  In .NET, pointer types are called *Reference Types* while non-pointer types are called *Value Types*.  Reference types are defined by classes.  Value types are defined by structures.  For instance:

```
Public Class MyReferenceType
    ' ...
End Class

Public Structure MyValueType
    ' ...
End Structure
```

Unlike some other languages, like C, where making a variable a pointer or not is determined separately for each variable, in .NET, it is defined once for the type and that decision globally affects all variables/objects of that type.  Reference type objects (class objects) are always stored on the heap and value type objects (structure objects) are always stored on the stack.

Comment: Ok ,Thank you ,Just one Q the new label will hold the Reference of the main label not all main label as same as pointers ?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking.  `Label` is a class.  Therefore, any `Label` variable that you declare will always act as a pointer.  Is that what you were asking?

Comment: Something close to that ,,, i think i get it ,thank you very much for your help , i can't vote you up cuze i have no noreputation.